# Addin loading in wrong version of Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2012

We had our solution in VS2010, but we are changing it to VS2012 now. Only the setup project needs changing of course, InstallShield in VS2012.

However, my actual question is with regards to an Addin that we have for Visual Studio. When the solution is installed, and one opens VS2012 (since I am testing the new installation) then it is picked up in the Tools menu and all is well.
We have a project in the solution which when debugged, opens a second instance of Visual Studio, and then in this instance one can get hold of the addin etc.
But, when I debug this project out of VS2012, it opens a VS2010 instance.

Where can I change this setting? What should I look for?

In the .Addin files I have changed the version to:

```
<HostApplication>
    <Name>Microsoft Visual Studio Macros</Name>
    <Version>11.0</Version>
</HostApplication>
<HostApplication>
    <Name>Microsoft Visual Studio</Name>
    <Version>11.0</Version>
</HostApplication>
```

Comment: Have you tried asking the creators of the plugin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The project that you debug probably have Debug - Start Action - Start External program - `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe` in project settings.

You need to change this path to your VS 2012 exe like `c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe`.

Comment: Excellent! I would never have found that on my own. Thanks so much!